# How can I use an Environmental Variable as a start of a directory location in powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I was given a powershell script by a coworker to try and figure out. I have very little expereince with it so I've gotten stuck.

We need to pull a user defined cmdlet from a .ps1 file form another part of the drive.

Normally you would do it something like this:

```
    . .\scripts\thing.ps1
```

But we want to use an environmental variable set in command prompt to start the location. We have something like:

```
    . $Env:JobDir\scripts\thing.ps1
```

But this returns the error

```
    . : The term '\scripts\thing.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Is there anyway to make something like this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to make it a string, otherwise it's interpreting the entire path as a variable.

```
"$Env:JobDir\scripts\thing.ps1"
```

or

```
$Env:JobDir + "\scripts\thing.ps1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
# build the path to the job  
$job = Join-path -Path $Env:JobDir -ChildPath "scripts\thing.ps1"

# execute the job
$job
```

or

```
.$("$Env:JobDir\scripts\thing.ps1")
```